# Should I put constants for my Rails project in environment.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to store a path for a special directory used by my Rails application. Should I store that in environment.rb, or is there another place this is meant to go?

```
THE_DIRECTORY_PATH = '/path/to/directory'
```

Let's assume my controllers + models or libraries in /lib need access as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a robust YAML-file approach that allows per-environment settings. Try [app_config](http://github.com/cjbottaro/app_config), which has loads of great features, including referring syntax like `AppConfig.the_directory_path`.

Comment: AppConfig looks interesting. I hate global constants floating around, so encapsulating things like that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

How about storing it in a YAML configuration file that gets loaded by an initializer? [This Railscast has the details](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file).

Answer (score 1):

If controllers need access to it, then a better place would be the `ApplicationController`.

Comment: It may be that only they need access. Not sure at this point. But if my controllers + models or libraries in /lib need access as well, would environment.rb be the place?

Comment: something about environment.rb just doesn't feel right, unless you have different paths for different environments. also, take a look at initializers in this configuration guide - http://guides.rails.info/configuring.html#using-initializers

Comment: I kinda hate constants like this. You really *have* to define them in each environment - almost certainly you'll want a different value for one of them in production.